# Why would someone use an amplitude modulation ratio lower than one in a power inverter?

Tags: pwm, inverter, three-phase, harmonics

We had a test the other day, and there was this question:

> What is the minimum DC voltage required to drive a PWM, half-bridge, three-phase, power inverter to 4160 Vrms? It should be possible to vary the output 5% (up and down).

No one was completely sure on the answer; after all we also had to calculate the THD% from a table that only provided values for Vllh/Vd for even values of ma up to 1.0.

We believe it had something to do with changing the amplitude modulation ratio of the inverter but am not sure it was the best method. After all, the minimum is obtained for ma=1.0 (0.612 in this case as it was tri-phase), but how to make sure it varies 5% up, considering that over ma=1 it enters overmodulation?

Answer (score 2):

4160VRMS is big and I would have thought a transformer would have been used to step up the voltage from a lower voltage DC powered 3 ph inverter but, assuming this is not the case you have to ask if the voltage requirement is line-voltage or phase-voltage. The question is not clear on this so I'm going to play safe and assume it means line voltage.

This means the phase voltage will be \$\sqrt3\$ lower at 2402VRMS. At this stage I will point out that if the zero in the question making 416V into 4160V is wrong then it should be easy to figure out the answer.

2402V RMS is a p-p voltage of 6792 volts and this will need to be the DC supply to the semiconductors. Simple as that. If you need 5% variation then raise the dc voltage by 5%. If you want to accomodate volt drop in the transistors then add another couple of volts.

So, just to be clear, to attain the output asked in the question I reckon a DC supply voltage of over 7132 volts is required. I don't know how much the output transistors will drop when hard-conducting but asssuming it's an IGBT maybe also add 3 more volts to the DC supply rail to be surer. 7135 volts DC.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Yeah, it is line-to-line voltage. I don't think it is possible to "add more dc voltage" once the DC has been supplied, it will remain constant. Any changes to output must be done with moduation. Also the 4160 is correct; but if you wish to use a smaller voltage it really isn't the gist of the problem.

Comment: I hope you don't feel that I am pressing you here, but if it was a simple answer then it wouldn't have been posted. If you use around 7132 VDC say the transistors have no drop and they work flawlessly, then how do you increase the output Vrms? Your fundamental will already be at maximum and the oermodulation region is not linear, so you will be adding a lot of harmonics, and that is not desired. I should say most of the theory for this question comes from UNDELAND's text, and its chapter on inverters: http://www.amazon.com/Power-Electronics-Converters-Applications-Design/dp/0471226939